# Is it possible to store the text in push notifications from an android app (not owned by me) in Google cloud?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, push-notification

There is a free app available on Google's play store which sends push notifications to your phone when certain events occur ("news" events). I would like to be able to somehow store/scrape these notifications and eventually save them onto the Google Cloud platform.

The closest thing I have done to this is writing a python web scraper but I have never done anything with mobile apps and have no idea if this is even possible.

I tried googling but I only get results about sending push notifications to apps you have written yourself using Firebase. Any help/pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the only way to directly integrate Android App Notifications with Google Cloud Platform is through Firebase Cloud Messaging [1]. However the flow is in the opposite direction (from GCP to Android), and some dependencies need to be present in the Android App folders (like google-services.json file of the Cloud Project needs to be present in the App folder). For that to happen, you need to have ownership of the app.

You can use Google Cloud Storage on Android [2] to transfer the notification data / payload, but still you need to have an app for that.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start

Comment: I was afraid that this might be the case, I unfortunately do not own the app. If you remove Google cloud from the equation, is it possible to access/store the push notifications from the app in another way?

Comment: Firebase 5 used to have a package called 'notifications', which allowed you to intercept notification data, as explained in this stack case [1]. Since Firebase 6, its not available. I'm not aware of any non-Google Cloud solution to this. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956098/how-to-access-notification-data-after-clicking-on-notification-firebase-cloud-m